# Batch file that is ran by a python script refuses to write to .txt files

Tags: python, batch-file, text

I've made sure the the batch file is actually being ran, the purpose of the python+batch file stuff is to automatically map to a shared drive location in an unused drive letter and then after the rest of the python script finishes, disconnect from the shared drive. The shared drive gets mapped correctly when I run the python script, it's just that the .txt files do not get created.

I've also tried to kill the subprocess after running, but that didn't work, text files still weren't being written,

```py
import configparser as cfgp
import sys
import os
import subprocess

drive_controller_path = os.path.abspath("bat_files/drive_controller.bat")

pro = subprocess.Popen(drive_controller_path)
```

This is basically the only relevant portion from the python script

```sh
@echo off

>temp.txt (
    net use * "\\IPADDRESS\FILEPATH" /user:MYDOMAIN\MYUSERNAME MYPASSWORD
)

set /p var=<temp.txt

set drive_letter=%var:~6,2%
echo %drive_letter% >>drive_letter.txt

cmd /k
```

And this is the batch file in question

When I run the drive_controller.bat by just clicking on it, the text files are created no problemo! Very confused. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: might be a permissions issue. did you check any of that? so essentially wrap the python code inside a try/except block and either log it or have the error be printed out

Comment: Maybe the files _are_ being created, but in a directory you didn't expect?  Try adding `print(os.getcwd())` to the python script to confirm the current directory.

Comment: John Gordon I owe you one!! haha, just checked the location of my python script, looks like the text files were being sent there! So to fix this I'd need to do a change directory and then after the batch file is done change directory again back to original, right?

Comment: Have you checked the content of variable `drive_controller_path`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that yes, the .txt files were being written to the directory the python script was located in. In order to get everything working, the simple fix was to move the .bat files to the same directory and make some minor changes to the calls. Thanks again John Gordon!